# Automatic backup and restore of Aerospike namespaces

Tags: namespaces, aerospike

I have a namespace 'test' in Aerospike. I can easily creates it backup and restore it using the following commands:

```
Backup:
asbackup -h localhost -n test  -d /home/asif/aerobckups -r

Restore:
asrestore -d /home/asif/aerobckups
```

But I need to explicitly run these commands. I want to do this operation in a way like: I have set TTL 30d in namespace. As TTL reaches so on 30th day it automatically creates backup and restore namespace (I will make backup and restore on different server). Is there any way to do it? if it is available as a property in namespace then it will be very nice but suggestions related to init.d are also welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing a bash script with the backup and restore commands in it. Set the script to automatically run after every 30 days.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Backup:
asbackup -h localhost -n test  -d /home/asif/aerobckups -r

#Restore:
asrestore -d /home/asif/aerobckups
```

Run it using:It will run every 4th week

```
0 0 * * 4 /home/ramesh/backup.sh
```